# Is there a better way use these two arrays together to achieve the same result?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of numbers called **elements**, and another array called **selection** which is a 3 x 3 array of 0's and 1's. If a 1 is selected it means increases sum by the corresponding element value from the elements array. Once all elements are added together it divides them by the number of selected elements.

How can I improve this code as it seems clunky and I am not sure it is very efficient?

```
   //Selection Array 
   selection = new int [][]{
                    {0,1,0,},
                    {1,1,1,},
                    {0,1,0}
                     };

//Calculate number selected
numberinselection=.....code to add up numbers in selection array above

//Add up selected elements

float sum=0;
sum +=2*elements[x][y][subject]*selection[1][1];
sum +=elements[x][yminus][subject]*selection[1][0];
sum +=elements[x][yplus][subject]*selection[1][2];              
sum +=elements[xminus][y][subject]*selection[0][1];
sum +=elements[xplus][y][subject]*selection[2][1];

sum = sum/numberinselection;
```

Comment: In addition, the elements array is much larger / a different size to the selection array.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      sum+=elements[i][j]*selection[i][j]
```

Try these codes.

Comment: Even if this is the correct solution, you should do something to explain *why* it's the correct solution.